# Please help identify this LEGO set

Tags: set-identification

Got it from bulk, please help identify the set.[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is Yoda's hut from Set # [4502-1: X-wing Fighter](https://brickset.com/sets/4502-1/X-wing-Fighter)

[image]

key part: [Tan Brick, Arch 1 x 6 x 2 Curved Top](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6183&colorID=2&in=A)

Comment: Thanks, great help.